# What was the last thing Batman said to Commissioner Gordon?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

Near the end of the [The Dark Knight Rises](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1345836/),

> Batman is about to fly off with the bomb to save Gotham City. Commissioner Gordon wishes to know who Batman is, so the city can know who this masked hero is. Batman mentions that the mask is a symbol, that anyone can be etc. 
>  He doesn't directly reveal that he's Bruce Wayne, but he says *something* before leaving. As Batman lifts off, the scene flashes to Gordon taking care of a young Bruce Wayne after his parents were killed. **Gordon figures out that Batman is Bruce Wayne.**

What did Batman say? And from that, how did Gordon figure it out?

The audio for Bane and Batman in this movie is a difficult to understand-- *I kind of wish there were subtitles.*

Comment: I was constantly looking down to the bottom for the subtitles...

Comment: “I’ve always loved you, Jim.”

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Bruce (as Batman) reminded Gordon that "sometimes it just takes a coat put on a small child and telling them everything will be okay" to get them to believe in law and order (paraphrased from memory there).

This is followed by a brief cut to footage of Gordon putting his coat on a young Bruce Wayne's shoulders after the death of Bruce's parents, before cutting back to a look of realization on Gordon's face (presumably he was recalling that incident at the same time as we were shown it).

Comment: I think the look of recognition were heightened by the realization: "Bruce Wayne."

Comment: Precisely, dlanod is right on spot. The climax was awesome

Comment: Apropos of this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUDHcuLnMVc

Comment: @iGameRam Most 'climaxes' *are* awesome!

Answer (score 25):

> Jim Gordon: I never cared who you were.
>
> Batman: And you were right.
>
> Jim Gordon: Shouldn't the people know the hero who saved them?
>
> Batman: ‎A hero can be anyone. Even a man doing something as simple and reassuring as putting a coat around a young boy's shoulders, to let him know the world hadn't ended.
>
> [Flashback of Gordon doing this for Bruce after his parents had been killed]
>
> Jim Gordon: Bruce Wayne?

From : http://en.wikiquote.org